# Rails way to create several "create" pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an "admin control panel" page which is handled by an `AdminController`. You can do two things in the control panel: `create_product` and `create_order`. There will be forms for each object, and when you submit the form, it will insert new records into the database.

What is the Rails way for implementing this? Do I generate a `CreateProductController` and `CreateOrderController` along with the appropriate view, which are accessible by clicking on the `create_product` and `create_order` links from the control panel?

Does the Rails way describe a way to handle both workflows using a single controller? At some point I will need to define a `post` method for each form, so it seems like creating separate controllers is the easiest way to set up required behavior and also the routing details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product and Order are all resources when having controller. The better way is to use RESTful resources. You can also add namespace for easier identification.

```
class Admin::ProductsController < AdminController

  def create
  end

  def new
  end

  # And #show, #index, #destroy etc.
end

class Admin::OrdersController < AdminController

  def create
  end

  def new
  end

end
```

Comment: You can use `scope :admin` to define the resource in routes.rb to make path like "admin/products/create". For your concern on the blog post, I think that's just a debate over names. If db attacked, it won't be the fault of RESTful resource.

Comment: I generated a model called `admin/product` and couldn't get the `scope :admin` to find my `ProductController`, but I tried `namespace :admin` instead and it found it.